# Unmasked WebSocket data is not understandable, when it is supposed to be

Tags: python, encryption, websocket, wireshark, xor

So while inspecting a packet off a pcap file, I saw a Websocket packet with that is supposed to send a picture (in this case we know how the header of the picture file is supposed to look, just to make things easy).

The data is masked, but the unmasked data also does not seem to match the picture's headers, even though it is supposed to.

Throughout the WS-handshake one of the sides sent a so called 'token' that matches the WS "magic number" pattern, but the handshake was successful, which means that it wasn't supposed to be an alternative to the WS' "magic number"...

I'd love to get any ideas on how to get the unmasked payload- maybe I am missing something about the WebSocket protocol?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And that doesn't apply only for the "picture" file, it also applies for other messages.

Comment: For example this message is supposed to show username and password in a JSON format. Picture: [link](http://prntscr.com/fsvt22)

Comment: What Wireshark version are you using? In 1.12 and older, the payload was not always unmasked, this was improved with Wireshark 2.0. Are there any special headers like `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions`?